# Unable to scan azure sql database using azure purview

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault, azure-purview

[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIEkt.png)

stored the connection string in azure key vault. I added the access policy that azure purview can access the azure key vault.
My connection string is :
Server=tcp:imagevalidation.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Imagevalidator;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sqllogin;Password=xxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

The same connection string works fine in azure data factory. I can authenticate that database using azure key vault.

Comment: Same here. Not having luck. Any tutorial that would get me going will be appreciated. All thats available is based on AD MSI